# Repeated jQuery with mouseover animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

My jQuery animation keeps repeating. It moves out of the mouse area, so mouseleave is triggered. If you then move the mouse a little bit, then it moves back, then mouseover is triggered. This way it keeps repeating. How can i fix this problem.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>       
        <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="upperaccent"></div>
            <div id="bottomaccent"></div>
            <div id="leftaccent"></div>
            <div id="rightaccent"></div>
        </div>  
            <div id="leftmenu">

                <a href="list.html">
                    <div class="icontext" id="icontext1" style="margin-top: 150px;">
                        <img class="menuicons" id="menuicon1" src="list.png">
                    </div>
                    <p class="tags" style="top: 150px;" id="tag1">Tasks</p>
                </a>

                <a href="calender.html">
                    <div class="icontext" id="icontext2">
                        <img class="menuicons" id="menuicon2" src="calender.png">
                    </div>
                    <p class="tags" style="top: 239px;" id="tag2">Calender</p>
                </a>

                <a href="settings.html">
                    <div class="icontext" id="icontext3">
                        <img class="menuicons" id="menuicon3" src="settings.png">
                    </div>
                    <p class="tags" style="top: 328px;" id="tag3">Settings</p>
                </a>

            </div>

        <div id="topmenu"></div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* background */

#background {
    background-color: #C5EFFD;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
}


/* menu's */

#leftmenu   {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

    height: 100%;
    width: 85px;
    background-color: #006295;
}

#topmenu    {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

    width: 100%;
    height: 7.5%;
    background-color: #BD2031;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.panel  {
    width: 65%;
    height: 92.5%;
    background-color: #9BE1FB;
    left: 85px;
    top: 7.5%;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

#leftBar    {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #006295;
    opacity: 0.25;
}

/* images */

.menuicons  {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

.icontext   {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.tags   {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #231F20; 
    left: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #0073af; 
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #0082af;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Calender */
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $("#tag1, #tag2, #tag3").hide();


    $("#menuicon1").mouseover(function()    {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.50, x: 25, rotateY: '360deg'})
        $("#icontext1").transition({x: 50})
        $("#tag1").show()
        $("#tag1").transition({x: 120});        
    });
    $("#menuicon1").mouseleave(function()   {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.00, x: 0, rotateY: '0deg'})
        $("#icontext1").transition({x: 00})
        $("#tag1").transition({x: 0})
        $("#tag1").hide(50);    
    });

    $("#menuicon2").mouseover(function()    {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.50, x: 25, rotateY: '360deg'})
        $("#icontext2").transition({x: 50})
        $("#tag2").show()
        $("#tag2").transition({x: 120});                        
    });
    $("#menuicon2").mouseleave(function()   {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.00, x: 0, rotateY: '0deg'})
        $("#icontext2").transition({x: 00})
        $("#tag2").transition({x: 0})
        $("#tag2").hide(50);        
    });

    $("#menuicon3").mouseover(function()    {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.50, x: 25, rotateY: '360deg'})
        $("#icontext3").transition({x: 50})
        $("#tag3").show()
        $("#tag3").transition({x: 120});                    
    });
    $("#menuicon3").mouseleave(function()   {
        $(this).transition({ scale: 1.00, x: 0, rotateY: '0deg'})
        $("#icontext3").transition({x: 00})
        $("#tag3").transition({x: 0})
        $("#tag3").hide(50);        
    });

});
```

An working example with jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hypertje/LUE5b/

Comment: Your problem is that mouseover does what it's supposed to do?  In that, when your mouse leaves and then enters again, it runs again?  Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is automattically triggered again, which makes it almost impossible to click on the link which is the icon.

Comment: You didn't post your jsFiddle so that would help me help you.  Help ME help YOU! :)

Comment: @user1477388 Btw, it isn't that you leave it on purpose, it automatically moves out, since the box moves.

Comment: @Bart See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

http://jsfiddle.net/LUE5b/2/

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $(".tags").hide();

    $(".menuicons").mouseover(function()    {

        if (!$(this).hasClass('current'))
        {
            $('.current').removeClass('current');

            $(this).transition({ scale: 1.50, x: 25, rotateY: '360deg'})
            $(this).parent().transition({x: 50})
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags').show()
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags').transition({x: 120});   
            $(this).addClass('current');

            $.each($('.menuicons'), function(){
                if (!$(this).hasClass('current'))
                {
                    $(this).transition({ scale: 1.00, x: 0, rotateY: '0deg'});
                    $(this).parent().transition({x: 00});
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags').transition({x: 0});
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags').hide(50);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: This is perfect, but just one question. Should there always be one icon enlarged, or is it possible that no icon is enlarged when you are busy with something somewhere else???

Comment: Could you include a description of what is different or why this works?

Comment: @roviuser I included the jsfiddle which says it all, no?  Basically, it does what the OP describes he wants.

Comment: @user1477388 Generally code-only answers are discouraged because it doesn't provide any explaination, it's just raw copy-pasta. You have no obligation to, but it helps the asker better understand the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter instead of mouseover

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, I'm sorry.